# ssh: connect to host 143.42.59.227 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vps, linode

I have two problems:

1. I can succesfully ssh to my remote Linode server from my wsl terminal (Debian) but since Im not that experienced programming in the terminal I want to use VScode. But as Im trying to ssh/use remote explore from VScode and it fails (which is my second issue), then after it fails I cant ssh from my wsl terminal, until the next day or something like that, why does this happen?

[SSH failed connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m987D.png)

2. Then the second issue is I cant ssh/use remote explore and connect to my remote server in VScode, I get this error:

[VScode failed SSH](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPuvH.png)

This is my C:\Users\jonas.ssh\config file
[C:\Users\jonas.ssh\config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAljt.png)

- I've tried uninstalling-installing OpenSSH on my local computer, but didn't help
- I've tried generating new ssh key on my local computer and adding to the linode server
- I've tried enabling password authentication, but get permission denied every time even though im using the right password
- I've run out of ideas...

Answer (score 0):

"Connection refused" means exactly what it says: you were unable to initiate a connection because the other end of the connection refused it. Your keys are irrelevant here, because the connection is refused before the key would even be used. (If I can't get *to* the locked house, then it doesn't really matter that I have that house's key in my pocket.)

Does that VM have SSHD running and listening on port 22? Does the firewall permit connections to that address on port 22? Do you have the correct address?

(Also: screenshots of text are not helpful. Copy and paste, please.)

Comment: Thank you. The first error doesn't happen anymore after i made sure to remove password auth from the server (this error only happened when I failed the password a number of times trying to ssh from VScode/PowerShell).

So my main issue is the fact that I cant ssh from VScode as I now get permission denied (I've also tried from PowerShell, which gives the same error)